# ASP.NET MVC 4 Client Side Validation Fails on Dates Containing Dots "."

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, date

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 4 website. I have a date field in one of my model classes which is formatted as **"dd.mm.yyyy"**. In my edit or create views, if I try to enter a date like "**05.12.1975**", server side validation works without any problems but client side Jquery validation fails and says that **"The field Birth Date must be a date."** But if I change the value to "**05/12/1975**" both of the validations work. Problem is about "." character in date field. How can I allow "." in client side validation?

Thanks.

**Date field in my C# Class file:**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
public virtual DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using client side validation for dates, you have to override the jQuery validation for date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd.MM.yyyy") !== null;
        }
    });
</script>
```

You have to reference the Globalize library and the appropriate culture in your HTML head. You can download it from https://github.com/jquery/globalize .